# Unbounded operator in Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, reference-request, set-theory

Suppose that $X$ is an infinite dimensional normed space over the field $\mathbb{K}$. Under the presense of **AC** (axiom of choice) we can show that $L(X,Y)\setminus B(X,Y)\neq\emptyset$ where $Y$  is an arbitrary normed space  and $L(X,Y)$ and $B(X,Y)$ are, respectively, the set of linear maps and bounded linear maps. I'm looking for an example consistent with **ZF** of a normed space $X$ such that $L(X,Y)=B(X,Y)$ for some normed space $Y$.

Does is there that example?

Any reference of source to read about this matter will be appreciate.

Comment: Take $Y=\{0\}$.

Comment: In ZF one cannot prove such a thing exists (when $X$ infinite-dimensional, $Y \ne 0$).  However, maybe you want to show that such a thing is *consistent* with ZF?

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, you are right. Fixed.